# AudioRecord.Read hangs indefinitely when running on a physical device

Tags: android, xamarin, audio, xamarin.android, audiorecord

I'm building a Xamarin.Android app that processes audio in real time, so I'm working on setting up AudioRecord. I have it working in the simulator, but when I run it on a device (Galaxy S9), the AudioRecord.Read() call never returns. This is puzzling because all of the contructor/StartRecording() both run fine with no exceptions, and the Recording state reports RECORDSTATE_RECORDING. It thinks it's recording, but read just can't get frames. Also, on the simulator, it runs fine and does successfully read from the buffer.

Here's the code. If you want to try it, create a blank Xamarin.Android app and replace the MainActivity.cs contents with this:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Media;
using Android;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using System;

namespace AndroidRecord
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {
                throw new Exception($"need record permission");
            }

            StartRecording();
        }

        protected void OnDataUpdate(float[] data)
        {
            // consume thse data.
            var max = data.Max(sample => sample);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{max}");
        }

        public void StartRecording()
        {
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                var audioSource = AudioSource.Mic;
                int sampleRate = 44100;
                var channelConfig = ChannelIn.Front;
                var encoding = Encoding.PcmFloat;
                int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.GetMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, encoding);

                AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRate, channelConfig, encoding, minBufferSize);
                recorder.StartRecording();

                int chunkSize = 2048;
                while (true)
                {
                    float[] data = new float[chunkSize];
                    int i = recorder.Read(data, 0, chunkSize, (int)(int)AudioRecordReadOptions.Blocking);
                    RunOnUiThread(() => OnDataUpdate(data));
                }
            })).Start();
        }
    }
```

So far I've tried:

1. Various combinations of AudioRecord options (different channel configs, audio sources, and encodings)
2. Various chunk sizes (doesn't seem to matter because I don't think there's anything to read)
3. Change the Read() call to non-blocking and check the return value. It doesn't write any values and returns success.
4. Pause the debugger to see what the stack trace says. Every time I break, the recording thread is in the same place, waiting on an interop call:

   ```
   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_call_int_method_a
   0x54 in Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallIntMethod
   0x2C in Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualInt32Method
   0x70 in Android.Media.AudioRecord.Read
   0x61 in AndroidRecord.MainActivity.<StartRecording>b__2_0
   ```

What else can I try to diagnose this problem or at least get some more info?

Answer (score 1):

I restarted my device and tried again, and go figure, now it works fine. My only guess is that the recording device was somehow left in a bad state, maybe from force-stopping my application from the debugger on a previous run. Just a guess though.

Answer (score 0):

I created a blank Xamarin.Android app and replaced the MainActivity.cs contents with your code, but I haven't reproduced your error. Instead, I got stucked in the permission checking section as following

```
if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {
                throw new Exception($"need record permission");
            }
```

I think there is something wrong with the permission requesting method, maybe [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) can help you.